# ng-repeat and ng-scrollbar doesn't work together

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scrollbar, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm just starting Angular JS and trying to have a scrollbar appearing as I add an element in the list which would be populated in the box of the contents. 
I installed ng-scrollbar from here. https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar

HTML:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/ng-scrollbar.min.css" >
  <style>
    .scrollme {
      max-height: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="DemoApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="DemoController">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <div class="scrollme" ng-scrollbar rebuild-on="rebuild:me" is-bar-shown="barShown">
            <tr>
                <th width="2%"></th>
                <th width="14%">Name</th>
                <th width="85%">Address</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="addImageButton.png" ng-click="addRow()" />
                </td>
                <td class="inlineBlock">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="row.name" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="row.addr" />
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr ng-repeat="row in rowList">
              <td>
                <img src="removeImageButton.png"ng-click="removeRow($index)" />
              </td>
              <td>{{row.name}}</td>
              <td>{{row.client}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
      </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('DemoApp', ['ngScrollbar']);
  app.controller('DemoController', DemoController);
  function DemoController($scope) {
    // portfolio and broker tabs
    $scope.row = {}
    $scope.row.name = "";
    $scope.row.addr = "";
    $scope.rowList = [];

    // adding a row to list
    $scope.addRow = function() {
      var data = {};
      data.name = $scope.row.name;
      data.addr = $scope.row.addr;
      $scope.rowList.push(data);
      $scope.row.name = "";
      $scope.row.addr = "";
      console.log($scope.rowList);
    }

    // removing a row from the list
    $scope.removeRow = function(obj) {
      console.log('end' + $scope.rowList);
      if(obj != -1) {
        $scope.rowList.splice(obj, 1);
      }
    }

    $scope.$on('scrollbar.show', function(){
        console.log('Scrollbar show');
      });

      $scope.$on('scrollbar.hide', function(){
        console.log('Scrollbar hide');
      });

//      $scope.$on('loopLoded', function(evt, index) {
//        if(index == $scope.me.length-1) {
//            $scope.$broadcast('rebuild:me');
//        }
//      });

  }

})();
```

It's part of my code so it might not fully make sense. But the way it works is that if I pressed the addImageButton, it would add a row which will add a row on the web. And conversely, removeImageButton will delete a row which will show on the web immediately. I need a scroll bar appearing once it reaches the height 100px. I checked the last answer of the [ng-scrollbar is not working with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663917/ng-scrollbar-is-not-working-with-ng-repeat) 
as well but it didn't work. Would be great if I could get some help with the detailed explanation. :) Thanks!

Comment: In documentation rebuild passed by an event. Have try to add :
  $scope.$broadcast('rebuild:me'); at the end of add and remove row function

Comment: @Silvinus Yes I have! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out! I need to put the broadcast method in addRow and removeRow methods. Also, I had to put the  out from the